# Laravel bcrypt asignement of mass

Tags: php, laravel, bcrypt

Hello that a fix if anyone have this problem with assignement of mass with password.

The problem is if you do this :

```
$exemple->password = $inputs['password'];
```

the database MySQL will take the plain text password.

What you need it's to do this :

```
$inputs['password'] = Hash::make($inputs['password']);
```

After this you can verify the password ago to push in database with a `dd()`:

```
 Hash::check('plain-text-password',$inputs['the hashed password'].
```

Comment: *"The problem is if you do this: `$exemple->password = $inputs['password'];` [...]"* - There any reason you can't just do `$example->password = Hash::make($inputs['password']);` instead in that case? I could be wrong, but I thought Laravel hashed the password field during `insert()` or `update()` methods (might have been a custom auth package, and not done with default `Auth` logic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a job for a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) if I understood your question correctly:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }
}
```

So every time you set the password with `$user->password = 'a safe password'` the mutator of this field will be called and hash your password.